# How to add contains or startswith in jq

Tags: linux, unix, jq

I have the following command:

```sh
echo "column1, column2, column3" > test.csv &&
cat data.json | jq -r '. | [.["column1"], .["column2"], .["column3"]] | @csv’ >> test.csv
```

It creates a column headings and the data from `data.json`.

I am trying to also add it where for example it only would pull data that contains the words (`"abc"`) from `column3`.

I added `|select(.column3| startswith ('ab'))` so the full command is:

```sh
echo "column1, column2, column3" > test.csv &&
cat data.json | jq -r '. | [.["column1"], .["column2"], .["column3"]] |select(.column3| startswith ('ab')) | @csv’ >> test.csv
```

but I get the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

my json.data looks like this:

```js
{
      "column1": "hello",
      "column2": "bye",
      "column3": "abc"
}
```

How do I parse `column3`? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `I added:` where and how did you add it? Please post the full command that you have tried. Please post sample data from `data.json`, enough so others can test it.

Comment: Thanks for asking, the full command is: 
echo "column1, column2, column3" > test.csv && cat data.json | jq -r '. | [.["column1"], .["column2"], .["column3"]] |select(.column3| startswith ('abc')) | @csv’ >> test.csv

Comment: @KamilCuk it’s hard to come up with the Json.data example though

Comment: Please give an indicative example of `data.json` -- one that is both illustrative and sufficient to replicate the error.

Comment: @peak I have added an example of the json.data

 {
      "column1": "hello",
      "column2": "bye",
      "column3": "abc"
    }

Comment: so I actually have a working code now, but it gives me true or false and it doesn't give me the filtered data.

Working code:
echo "column1, column2, column3" > test5.csv && cat data.json | jq -r '. | [.["column1"], .["column2"], .["column3"]|startswith("ab")] | @csv' >> test5.csv

Comment: What if your object doesn't match? You want a CSV file with just the header row?

Comment: @Shawn yea if it doesn’t match I want it gone. I am basically trying to just filter it and get raid of the rest.

Comment: @Shawn I mean, if row 1, column3 has the match, I still one column1 and column2 to have that data on that row. But if row3 column3 doesn’t match then I want that whole row dropped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easier to filter before converting the object to an array for `@csv`:

```sh
$ (echo "column1,column2,column3";
   jq -r 'select(.column3 | startswith("ab"))
          | [.column1, .column2, .column3]
          | @csv' data.json) > test.csv
$ cat test.csv
column1,column2,column3
"hello","bye","abc"
```

But if you do want to convert to an array first, you then have to `select` using the appropriate array index:

```
jq -r '[.column1, .column2, .column3]
       | select(.[2] | startswith("ab"))
       | @csv' data.json
```

---

Note how I enclosed the `echo` and `jq` in a set of parenthesis so they both run in the same subshell, and the output redirection outside of it, instead of having to redirect the output of both commands. Also gets rid of the Useless Use Of Cat; `jq` takes input filenames as arguments. Even if it didn't, input redirection is better than `cat`.

Comment: thank you for this! However, the actual json I am using I guess isn't a string maybe as I had thought...cause it gives me the following error: "startswith() requires string inputs" 
it's a json with over million entries so it's hard to figure out what it is or why I am getting that error. But your answer is super helpful and thank you again!

Comment: ah only a few rows were having that error, so that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @artemisia480 'over a million entries'? 'a few rows'? If your real input isn't a file with a single json object, your sample input in the question shouldn't be a single object either.

Comment: I agree with you, my real json is very nested and hairy, I was having a hard time trying to replicate it. I truly appreciate your answer and it is working so thank you again.